# C# Not recognizing resources, why?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to build a C# Program (https://github.com/f1r3fr0st/ajart-studio-edit). First, I tried to load the file but I had the wrong .NET version. I was able to update to 4.6.2 though.

When I attempt to build the project, I get a multitude of errors which claim that the resources were not able to be found (PcapDotNet, NAudio, AMF3SpecCli, etc.) even though they are all in the project's "Resources" section. Somehow, I have no idea how to replicate it, I was able to get most of the errors to dispensary, with AMF3SpecCli being the only one not to work. It seems like sometimes the only build error is AMF3SpecCli not existing, sometime's it's all of them. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Are you sure you've got the name right? Because typically it's *References* that are the problem, not *Resources*. They're also usually called Dependencies in VS2019. Resources are things like icons and strings...

Comment: I just copied the code from this repository,,, do I need to rename something?

Answer (score 0):

Based on research, I can build and run the app successfully.

Please refer to the following steps to build your app.

First, Please set your warning level to be 0.
[image]

Second, Please find the Main.rex file and click Unlock and apply it.
[image]

Third, please delete the AMF3SpecCLI in your current references and add it from resource.

Fourth, please delete the iso file.

Finally, you can build the project successfully and run it.
[image]